# thymeleaf - pass variable to modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, thymeleaf

I open the modal like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upload">Upload</button>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to pass a thymeleaf variable to the modal.

I only found a question where Angular.js was used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to open modal dialog manually like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    // Do your job
    $('#upload').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! Can I pass a variable to the modal that way?

Comment: Modal is not a function or object that you can pass parameter. If you want to  do some change on modal contents you must do it manually.

Comment: okay. I am trying to load an image in the modal. In order to load the right image I need to pass an id in the request url like this:
<img id="preview" th:src="@{/get_image(id=${id})}"/>

Comment: $('#preview, $('#upload')).attr('src', 'img url'); // it must be something like this.

Comment: i got it!
$('#preview').attr('src', '/get_image?id='+id)